# Codeigniter 2.1 - redirect to current url after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I redirect to current url after logout?

HTLM for logout:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>korisnik/logout">Logout</a>
```

Controller function:

```
function logout() { 
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[yAnTar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099288/398242) has the right idea (storing the last url in the current one), but CI urls don't normally accept all characters in a base64 encoded string (like `=`). Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>korisnik/logout?last_url=<?php echo urlencode(current_url())">Logout</a>
```

```
function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect($this->input->get('last_url'));
}
```

Another option could be to redirect to `$this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER')`, but I've had issues with that in the past (old version of Google Chrome sending `favicon.ico`) and don't normally recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in logout function

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('redirect_url', current_url());
```

And now in your other method

```
if($this->session->flashdata('redirect_url'))
{
   $url = $this->session->flashdata('redirect_url');
   redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: `current_url()` in the logout function would be the logout url (infinite loop). I guess by "other method" you mean "every controller", so 2 redirects?

Comment: I guess what I meant was that you'd have to set the flashdata in every controller, every time. Seems like a burden, but otherwise this method is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can add url like a first option in method logout

```
<a href="/korisnik/logout/<?php echo base64_encode(current_url());?>"
```

Next in your function

```
public function logout($url){
    redirect(base64_decode($url));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only asking for redirect then some thing like this can help in your problem.

```
$url= base_url().'index.php/korisnik/logout'; 
redirect($url);
```

From what i see either your `base_url()` has some problem or you are missing `index.php` in URL please check.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following code in my controller's construct when I ran into this problem:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('last_url' => current_url()));
```

I'd setup a favicon and then after a while I started noticing that I was being redirected to favicon.ico on the few functions that used last_url.

I eventually figured out the problem. I just added favicon.ico to my htaccess file and it works perfectly now.

Here's the .htaccess line:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|slider|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
```

I hope this helps someone else.